# How to use %p with additional lines in Haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I am receiving the following error:

```
Illegal nesting: content can't be both given on the same line as %p and nested within it.
```

This is my code:

```
- @docs.each do |doc|
%h2= link_to doc.title, doc
%p= time_ago_in_words(doc.created_at)
%p= truncate(doc.content, length:50)

    = link_to "Create Doc", new_doc_path
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You are getting down-votes, most likely because your question doesn't show adequate research. Your starting point is http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#ruby-evaluation, which describes using `%p=`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you supply content on the same line as a tag in Haml, you are saying "The content of this tag will only be whatever is in this line, and close the tag immediately".

So

```
%p hello
```

becomes

```
<p>hello</p>
```

In situations where you have more than one line for a tag, use a newline and indentation to indicate the content for that block:

```
%p
  Hello
  World
```

Which results in:

```
<p>Hello\nWorld</p>
```

You are trying to use both of them here. You are supplying the content for the short form tag, but also indenting as if you plan on continuing to add content to your `p` tag.

To fix this you need to use the multiline syntax, if that is your intent, or remove the indentation from your `link_to`:

```
- @docs.each do |doc|
  %h2= link_to doc.title, doc
  %p= time_ago_in_words(doc.created_at)
  %p
    = truncate(doc.content, length:50)
    = link_to "Create Doc", new_doc_path
```